# Why not use a 3w brushed motor to drive the larger 3000w brushless motor by rotating the conductor pattern mechanically?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

Essentially the smaller motor would be rotating the conductor connections in the same pattern that the motor controller would do, except it wouldnt be solid state. Is there something wrong with that design?  This motor controller on ebay is $180 to $120 for the chinese supplier. What I just described would be less than $5.

It would still have the benefits of brushless but then be more accessible like a normal brushed motor. Any friction from the conductors would be on the much smaller load.

I bought the motors for like $40 less (than the chinese supplier) so paying more for the controller is sorta hilarious right?

[image]

Comment: "It would still have the benefits of brushless" possibly the biggest benefit of a brushless motor is that _it doesn't have brushes to wear out_.  Basically all you're proposing to do is to have an externally commutated motor with a mechanical commutator driven by a separate motor.  So for nearly any application, you're combining the _worst_ aspects of a brushless motor (needs a controller) and a brushed motor (has brushes and a commutator).  Then you're adding in the lack of synchronization, at no extra charge.

Comment: No no no, that was the point, you would be replacing the controller with the mechanical commutator driven by the 3w dc motor... you increase and decrease the 3w to increase and decrease the 3000w... The 3w motor is $1 on ebay if you dont want to waste your life replacing finnicky brushes...  lol, we are definitely not synced, are you being paid to answer my questions lol?

Comment: I see your disrespect (saying "lol" certainly doesn't negate it), and reply _with respect_.  "rotating the conductor connections" -- that is **commutation**.  You'll need conductors in a certain pattern (that's called **a commutator**) to time the switching, you'll need slip rings, and you'll need connections to the commutator and slip rings -- and those connections are called **brushes**.  Even if your $1 motor lasts forever, your 3kW commutator and brushes will wear.  You're not making a "mechanically switched brushless motor" -- you're making a multi-part, complicated, brushed motor.

Comment: That is a good point, it would wear... I dont know how long is usual, are you suggesting the larger watts will regularly burn out brushes?  I guess I still dont understand... its just a piece of metal being pushed onto a central shaft (or would that be an outer connection?) by a spring while rotating... surely once every ten years is reasonable?  Why isnt it a mechanically switched brushless motor?  If the real load is still being driven by the brushless part...  I'm ok with a complicated brushed motor if I still get those larger watts that brushless have...  Grateful for your time :-)

Comment: You felt like I wasnt respectful, I guess my lol is sorta this dishonest thing because it just seems blatantly obvious that there's some sort of corruption going on... its like these brushless hub motors for the scooters, there's nothing that requires it to be brushless, it could be brushed hub motors, maybe slightly differently like the wheels in the front of an airplane where the shaft extends out to both sides, but this nothing but brushless for regular consumers when brushed is so much easier... and the controller is a lot more $ where with brushed you can go directly off the battery

Comment: Brushes wear, are electrically noisy and lossy. Brushless avoids these issues as well as bring able to alter the commutation angle to improve the torque spread. Using a smaller motor to commutate a larger one is Wile Coyote - esq in its conception.

Comment: What happens if the 3w motor gets out of sync? That would be bad for the 3kw motor

Comment: It would work, but... The mechanical commutator would have ... brushes. You can even optimise the configuration further by fixing the commutator to the main motor shaft and eliminating the second motor!

Comment: lol what?  how would you fix the commutator to the main shaft?  like you crank the thing to get it going or something?

Comment: It seems you still don't realize that what you are proposing is just a brushed motor exploded up. A brushed motor is just the stator, rotor, coils, and magnets, slip rings, and brushes all sitting on the same shaft. Your proposal is removing the slip rings and brushes off the shaft outside of the motor to leave a brushless motor behind, and splitting off a small portion of the stator, rotor, coils, and magnets to make a second smaller motor and then giving it its own brushes and slip rings (which are just duplicates of the other ones but smaller).

Comment: But in the end for synching you still need to have the brushed motor and the brushless motor sharing the same shaft anyways. So in the end all you have done is disemboweled a brushed motor along the same shaft. "*how would you fix the commutator to the main shaft?*" It's very reasonable and very simple and the fact you don't seem to get it indicates you still don't understand what it is you are proposing. In a sense, it is just like removing the passenger cab from the car and hooking it up behind the engine wheels and drive train so it is dragged behind like a carriage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for a brushless motor to turn properly, you need the commutation of phase currents to be synchronzied to the rotor position. I literally have a giant mechanical commutator at work which operates exactly the way you describe and it sucks because it can't synchronize to the main motor. That means that if you load down the main motor, the main motor's rotor lags behind the commutator motor's rotor which happily keeps spinning and you lose synch and torque as the commutator rotor laps the main rotor again and again. I was asked to build a solid-state solution that could commutate based on rotor shaft position.

That means that now you need one of two things:

1. Solid-state electronics monitor the rotor position on the main motor
   and drive the commutator motor accordingly. This would require that
   the driver for the brushed motor be bidirectional so it could move
   the brushed motor backwards if required to synch with the brushless
   motor.

   This type of drive requires 4 transistors
   which is already 2/3 of what is required for a brushless motor
   drive. And the fact you need any electronics at all already defeats
   your original objective.
2. Or couple the shaft of the main motor and commutator motor together
   directly or with chains, gears, or belts, and position the
   commutator    rotor so its shaft is always equal to the main rotor
   (or a bit ahead,    known as phase advance).

   But this is obviously pointless since you could just move the
   brushes into the brushless motor and have the motor move the brushes
   itself and get rid of the commutator motor entirely. But then this
   just leaves you with a brushed motor.

Then there is the issue that your mechanical switching of the brushless motor currents has to be done with brushes that have to pass all the higher power of the motor just like a brushed motor. In your example you talked about using a 3W motor to turn the mechanical commutator for a 3kW brushless motor. Well, I doubt you'll get away with 3W. You need to turn a mechanism capable of conducting all the current of the brushless motor which means it will be big, and heavy. More like 100W, or even 200 or 300W.

I think you will find that if you actually sat down and started designing such a mechanism, it will be a lot more complex than when you originally envisioned it as a high level concept. The one at my work required a lot of brushes, slip rings, and contacts. Very expensive and noisy as all hell. Easy to describe, difficult to execute.

> but this nothing but brushless for regular consumers when brushed is so much easier... and the controller is a lot more $ where with brushed you can go directly off the battery

> because it just seems blatantly obvious that there's some sort of corruption going on... its like these brushless hub motors for the scooters, there's nothing that requires it to be brushless, it could be brushed hub motors, maybe slightly differently like the wheels in the front of an airplane where the shaft extends out to both sides,

No conspiracy as far as why there are no brushed motors commutating brushless motors as per everything I said above. It literally doesn't work or is vastly suboptimal if you add the stuff to make it work

Now you could argue that there should be brushed motors on the market because you can run them directly off the battery. Even if you needed speed control so could not run them straight off the battery, as long as you only needed unidirectional rotation you could use a speed controller that requires only 1 transistor.

However, if you need bidirectional control that takes four transistors and a brushless motor only requires two more transistors and has vastly improved performance. I don't think this point applies to brushed motors for bikes though.

But one point that does still apply to bikes is that you're running off a battery and batteries have terrible energy density so efficiency is really important and brushed motors aren't as efficient as brushless motors.

> That is a good point, it would wear... I dont know how long is usual, are you suggesting the larger watts will regularly burn out brushes? I guess I still dont understand... its just a piece of metal being pushed onto a central shaft (or would that be an outer connection?) by a spring while rotating... surely once every ten years is reasonable?

You're missing a very important aspect of brushes: For the types of motors you are talking about the actual brush itself at the end of the spring is of CARBON because of a few characteristics:

- conductive
- self-lubricating
- doesn't corrode
- it is soft so it *WEARS* down

That's right, brushes aren't designed to wear as little as possible. You actually want the brush to wear because you get to choose for the much more expensive, difficult to replace slip ring to wear or for the brush to wear. You also want it to wear so that constantly conforms to the slip ring for maximum contact.

I think you're underestimating how maintenance heavy and inefficient brushes are. My understanding is that when people in the model airplane and truck world were mostly using brushed motors, the brushes would get replaced once every season or something like that, and remember these guys are probably only flying every weekend. The model airplane and truck world moved from brushed to brushless motors long ago and got much better performance for it. This is somewhat obfuscated by the introduction of much better batteries, but you can still get brushed motors for certain models and they do not perform nearly as well even with modern batteries.

Comment: The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore it has been moved to chat and should be continued there (link below). --- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once, any further comments posted here to discuss the answer, might be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat, please!** Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128597/discussion-on-answer-by-dknguyen-why-not-use-a-3w-brushed-motor-to-drive-the-lar).